A Level Mechanics Question - why does frictional force reverse direction?
I am struggling with understanding part b) in the question below. (My question will come after the pasted text).

A beam AB has mass m and length 2a.
The beam rests in equilibrium with A on rough horizontal ground and with B against a
smooth vertical wall.
The beam is inclined to the horizontal at an angle θ.
The coefficient of friction between the beam and the ground is μ.
The beam is modelled as a uniform rod resting in a vertical plane that is perpendicular
to the wall.


Using the model,
(a) show that  μ <= (1/2)cot θ.
A horizontal force of magnitude kmg, where k is a constant, is now applied to the beam
at A.
This force acts in a direction that is perpendicular to the wall and towards the wall.
Given that  tan θ = (5/4),
μ = (1/2), and the beam is now in limiting equilibrium,
(b) use the model to find the value of k.

My question is: in the mark scheme, after the new horizontal force is applied, it assumes that the frictional force reverses direction to oppose it, and therefore acts perpendicular to the wall, and away from the wall. How was this deduced? Because it wasn't necessarily the case that the frictional force was at its maximum before, so why couldn't the new horizontal force have still not been enough to overcome it?

If you stand on the ground, nothing moves, you with the ground under your feet rest in equilibrium. Thus the ground compensates your weight force. If you step away the ground without you still rests in equilibrium. Now with this insight regard your beam: how big must the force be at minimum to make it move? (disregading dynamic effects)

For the premise of the question to be valid, you should have the first result with the inequality in the opposite direction, so that a minimum value of $\mu$ is established for equilibrium to be possible. Please check the question.
